# Cannot find adb.exe in specified SDK path using VS2017

Tags: android, mobile, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to tell vs2017 where to find adb.exe. When I select android-sdks/platform tools, the system returns android-sdks/platform tools/platform tools, which is why it is not finding the file.

Is there anyway to prevent the system from adding the extra platform tools folder is its search.

I am trying to test a mobile web application on an android emulator, and cannot specify where the emulator is located

Answer (score 0):

Selected the android folder instead of platform tools